# Android import non-built-in type in AIDL

Tags: android, aidl

Is there something specific I have to do to import a non-built-in type in an AIDL interface? Specifically MediaPlayer. When I try to import it i get the compile error "couldn't find import for class android.media.MediaPlayer".

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you can't reference android.media.MediaPlayer from an AIDL interface. To include MediaPlayer in an aidl file, it needs to have an associated aidl interface file or it needs to be Parcelable. Neither of these is true.

Could you describe in more detail what you are trying to achieve? There could be a better approach to solve your problem.

Comment: Well, I was initially trying to make a Service that included a mediaplayer object, but I was having problems - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966653/android-cant-bind-to-service . No solution was found and someone suggested I try using an AIDL interface, so here I am.

Comment: I believe it needs to have an associated aidl interface file AND implement the Parcelable interface.